# PHP Error on if statment

Tags: php

I keep getting this error:

> PHP Error Message
>       Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in
>   /home/a6941725/public_html/php/usersystem/signup.php on line 4

Here is the code:

```
if (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Main WHERE username LIKE $_POST['username']"); !== "$_POST['username']") {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
}
```

I am normally good at php but I can't figure out why it is not working!

Comment: remove the `;` after `$_POST['username']")`

Comment: The semi-colon in the middle of the line is the problem

Comment: I agree with @Jens remove the *;*

Comment: **Stop** using deprcated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead

Comment: My hosting don't allow MySQLi

Comment: removing ; does not work

Comment: Then you need to change hosting provider because they are screwing you over.

Comment: it's 000webhost.com

Comment: I doubt that your host does not let you use mysqli. I used to use that (awful) host a few years ago with both mysqli and pdo.

Comment: ohh.. ok but I find mysql easier

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try it like,

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Main WHERE username LIKE '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$result = mysql_query($query);// gives result
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['username'] !== $_POST['username']) { // remove quotes from post field
       $username = $_POST['username']; 
       break;// if both are not same then break
    }
}
```

Also [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) is removed in **PHP 7** so use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Im using php 5 and thanks it worked!

Comment: im new so I cant vote

Comment: @RohanKumar: It's not uncommon for answers with blatant SQL injections to get down-voted.  Granted, the OP also had that problem.  Just saying, it could be the reason.

Comment: Not my downvote neither but you may have gotten it because of putting in an answer for such a minimal issue and the fact about the amount of rep you have there Rohan.

Comment: Actually OP is using code in a wrong way and the logic was not clear for him, as he was trying to compare a mysql result with a string which is not correct. Of course he need more to learn from Google, but if he posted a question on SO then SO users must help him at least to increase his courage.

Comment: What you just wrote in your comment now, may have been what you should have written rather than just your opening statement. Maybe that's why the person downvoted. We hardly ever know when they do.